# Binding behavior of DynamicObject binary operation differs depending on operator and operands

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime, binary-operators

According to the documentation for [TryBinaryOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trybinaryoperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this method will be called when the left hand side of a binary operation is a dynamic object.

I've got a class that derives from dynamic object and am seeing that doesn't always seem to be the case. For this example I would expect 3 calls to my override `TryBinaryOperation` but only get 2.

```
public class MyDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryBinaryOperation(BinaryOperationBinder binder, object arg, out object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("operation = " + binder.Operation.ToString());
        result = arg;
        return true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        dynamic d = new MyDynamic();

        dynamic d1 = d + "add it";
        dynamic d2 = d + 1;
        dynamic d3 = d >> "shift it";

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine(d1);
        Console.WriteLine(d2);
        Console.WriteLine(d3);
    }
}
```

The first invocation however returns the string "`DynamicRestProxy.UnitTests.MyDynamicadd it`"; i.e. `d.ToString() + "add it"` is being called by the addition operator instead of trying the binary operation of my dynamic class. Further if the right hand operator of "+" is an int the dynamic operation is attempted.

The output of the above program is (notice that the call `d + "add it"` does not get to `TryBinaryOperation`):

```
operation = Add
operation = RightShift

DynamicRestProxy.UnitTests.MyDynamicadd it
1
shift it
```

where I would expect it to be

```
operation = Add
operation = Add
operation = RightShift

add it
1
shift it
```

Is this correct expected behavior? If so is there any more documentation somewhere that would explain?

*This is using VS.NET 2013 and .NET 4.5.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 dynamic d1 = d + "add it";
```

That's not a binary operation, that's *string concatenation*.  Documented in the MSDN article for DynamicObject.TryBinaryOperation(), the *Add* operation has this description:

> An addition operation without overflow checking, **for numeric operands**.

The binder already knows how to concatenate strings.  All that's required is to get your DynamicObject converted to a string.  Which you can see by adding the ToString() override:

```
    public override string ToString() {
        return base.ToString();
    }
```

Set a breakpoint on it and look at the call stack when it breaks:

> ConsoleApplication327.exe!ConsoleApplication327.MyDynamic.ToString() Line 22    C#
>       mscorlib.dll!string.Concat(object arg0, object arg1) + 0x1e bytes
>       System.Core.dll!System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, object arg0, string arg1) + 0x2ae bytes
>       ConsoleApplication327.exe!ConsoleApplication327.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 30 + 0x146 bytes   C#

Line #30 is the `d1` assignment statement in my test program.

Comment: Also interesting to see that the DLR is not on the stack. You only see the compiled callsite delegate.